# Segulos pertaining to individual Gemara Mesechtos

Tags: talmud-gemara, segulah

Are there certain segulos for learning certain Gemara Mesechtos (Bavli or Yerushalmi)?

Comment: Why would you think there are?

Comment: Do you mean a Segulah to help you learn those things or what learning those things is a Segulah for?

Comment: I've seen a few before. Learn Mesechtos Sukah for Shalom Beis (סגולות מעשיות:שלום בית) Learning Mesechtas Taanis is a segulos for Motzi Zera L'vatala (ספר קדושת ישראל :ערך מסכת) @donielIF. Then I saw in the back of a the Teztel Katan Published by: Israel Bookshop Publications, that one who learns Mesechtas Brachos - It's a Bracha for him.

Comment: For mishnayos I've seen a bunch. But for Gemara I haven't seen as many. Although, I have seen plenty segulos pertaining to "learning" Gemara. But not assigned to a specific tractate.

Comment: General Masechta learning is said to be a segula for many items

Comment: @Moshe You should include that in your question.

Comment: After Rabbi Yosef Dov Soloveichik lost his mother, brother, and wife in one year, he took some time off to grieve; then returned to YU and instead of continuing *Chezkas HaBatim*, he announced that he would teach *Eilu Megalchin BeMoed* (the laws of mourning, in *Moed Katan*); he said his family had a tradition that studying those laws were a segulah for long life. R' Dovid Miller observed -- "okay, that's how he dealt with his grief."

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best segulah a person can have. I have copied the link here: https://www.hidabroot.com/article/193322/My-Name-is-Chagigah

Brief description that man learned the tractate of Chagigah every day for thirty years some say sixty, when he passed away the Mesachta of Chagigah wept for him.

If person who is not so righteous but yet studied something wholeheartedly for the rest of his life, a segulah for him could be for the making of the next world.

Comment: This isn’t necessarily tied to a particular masechta. It just happened that he learned Chagigah his entire life. Had he learned a different masechta, perhaps that one would weep for him instead.

Comment: I read this in Kav HaYashar.